# How can I return a row for each date, even when there is no data for that date (in which case the row should be filled with zero's)?

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I hope I will be able to make my problem clear.

Ik have a table called `tweets` from which I want to extract information for each data in the `daterange` table. This table holds 142 dates, of which 102 dates have the property `trading` (day on which market was open) set to 1 (`trading=1`).

The below query extracts information from the `tweets` table for 20 companies (identified by `sp100_id`). The expected resultset therefore contains 20 x 102 = 2,040 rows. **However**, I only get returned 1,987 rows because for some date-company combinations, the `tweets` table holds no data. I need these "empty days" to be included in the resultset however. I thought I could accomplish this by using `COALESCE(X, 0)`, returning `0` if there would be no data, but the result is the same: 1,987 rows.

Based on this information and the query below, does anybody know how I can get it to return 102 rows (1 row for each `daterange._date` with `trading=1`) for each `sp100_id` in the `tweets` table?

```
SELECT
  sp100.sp100_id,
  daterange._date,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=2, tweets.`retweet_count`, 0)),0) AS `pos-retweet`,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=2, tweets.`user-quality`,  0)),0) AS `pos-quality`,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=2, tweets.`follow`,        0)),0) AS `pos-follow`,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=3, tweets.`retweet_count`, 0)),0) AS `neg-retweet`,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=3, tweets.`user-quality`,  0)),0) AS `neg-quality`,
  COALESCE(SUM(IF(tweets.classify1=3, tweets.`follow`,        0)),0) AS `neg-follow`
FROM
  sp100
CROSS JOIN
  daterange
LEFT JOIN
  tweets
  ON tweets.nyse_date = daterange._date
  AND tweets.sp100_id  = sp100.sp100_id
WHERE sp100.sp100_id BETWEEN 1 AND 20 AND tweets.type != 1 AND daterange.trading = 1
GROUP BY
  sp100.sp100_id, daterange._date
```

In any other case, I would provide you with a SQLFiddle, but it would be a lot of work to export a proper portion of the tables used to SQLFiddle while the solution might be clear to some real SQL guru anyway :-)

Comment: outer join onto a calendar table that is guaranteed to have all dates.

Comment: the table that is guaranteed to have all the dates is called `daterange`, and I'm `CROSS JOIN`ing it. Replacing this with `RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN` returns an error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE sp100.sp100_id BETWEEN 1 AND 20 AND tweets.type != 1 AND daterange.trading'"

Comment: You shouldn't be cross joining on it and your where clause converts the outer join back to an inner join. The condition on tweets needs to go in the on clause.

Comment: Thats great. It now works like a charm. Thanks :-) If you want the karma, post your answer seperately, so I may check it as the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from requiring that `tweets.type != 1` in your `WHERE` clause.

For the dates that have no associated tweets, the outer join will result in all `tweets` columns, including `tweets.type`, being `NULL`.  As documented under [Working with `NULL` Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html):

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.
>
> In MySQL, `0` or `NULL` means false and anything else means true. The default truth value from a boolean operation is `1`.

Therefore such records are filtered by your `WHERE` clause.

As [@Martin Smith commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239597/how-can-i-return-a-row-for-each-date-even-when-there-is-no-data-for-that-date#comment16404545_12239597), you can move this filter criterion into the `ON` clause of your outer join (so that the test is performed only against actual `tweets` records rather than simulated `NULL` ones).

Alternatively, you could rewrite the filter to handle `NULL`.  For example, using the [`NULL`-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
NOT tweets.type <=> 1
```

As an aside, I usually don't bother with a `daterange` table and instead omit dates for which there is no data from the resultset: instead, I handle missing dates within my application code.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that there is a small difference between these two approaches.  If there are records in the `tweets` table which have `type IS NULL`, then the first approach will exclude them from the resultset whereas the second approach will include them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a calendar table filled with each day. I know it might sound silly, but this solution solves yo a lot of problems. The same solution you can have also with integers ( integer tables)

Comment: I do have a calendar table: `daterange`. It hold all possible dates.